# Issue with setFont on chart (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jfreechart

I'm new to java. I'm trying to create a simple GUI with swing with button, which change the font of chart from JFreeChart library. However when I use chart.setFont, it makes a GUI freezed for a couple of seconds. I read that I should use setFont in other thread to avoid the problem but it doesn't seem work for me - probably I'm doing it wrong. I put my code below:

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
public final class Main{
    Main(){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        DefaultCategoryDataset data=new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createBarChart("Title", "Name", "Grade", data, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, false, false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel=new ChartPanel(chart);
        JPanel subPanel=new JPanel();
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JButton button=new JButton("Click");     
        setButton(chart, button);
        setChart(data);
        setSubPanel(subPanel, chartPanel);
        setPanel(panel, button, subPanel);
        setFrame(frame);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setFrame(JFrame frame){
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public void setPanel(JPanel panel, JButton button, JPanel subPanel){
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(subPanel);
    }
    public void setSubPanel(JPanel subPanel, ChartPanel chartPanel){
        subPanel.add(chartPanel);
    }
    public void setButton(final JFreeChart chart, JButton button){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
    public void setChart(DefaultCategoryDataset data){
        data.addValue(1, "abc", "");
        data.addValue(2, "def", "");
        data.addValue(3, "ghi", "");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Main frame=new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to solve it or give any tip how should I use thread in that case?

Comment: I don't know anything about JFreeChart, but your basic code looks correct. The setFont() should NOT be done in another thread. Any time you change the property of a component it should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. Your code is correct because the code executed in a listener is executed on the EDT. The SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you for answer camickr, however the problem still exists. I used a simple JLabel instead of chart but label.setFont() freezes GUI for a few seconds as well. When I use e.g setText(), the GUI refreshes automatically. Any solution?

Comment: +1 for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If your new code just uses a JLabel then you need to repost your example SSCCE, because I'm guessing many people don't have access to JFreeChart (I know I don't) so we can't execute your code to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @camickr: My error; the example depends on `JFreeChart`. I've had the JAR on my classpath for so long, I forgot. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine on my implementation. You might try this variation to see if using the existing font helps. As suggested by @camickr, the `invokeLater()` is not needed on the EDT.

```
public void setButton(final JFreeChart chart, JButton button) {
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TextTitle title = chart.getTitle();
            Font font = title.getFont();
            float size = font.getSize();
            title.setFont(font.deriveFont(size + 2));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Code [updated](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8780530/revisions) to use correct `deriveFont()` overload.

Comment: Thanks trashgod for a hint. I don't know why, but the problem was in font family. When I changed "Sans-Serif" to "Dialog" the freeze on GUI disappeared. Thanks again!

Comment: Aha, the family name is "SansSerif"; I habitually use the constant, [`Font. SANS_SERIF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#SANS_SERIF).